# Azure AD Sign In

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I have a web application that is secured by Azure AD. I would like to be able to allow some people to access this application. I have created an account in my directory for these users and I would like to log them in without doing a redirect to Azure AD.

Is there any way to get an Azure auth cookie and allow them to access my application without redirecting them to a login? I know the username / password and would like to be able to do the sign in behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail on why you would like to skip AAD sign-in? Is it because you'll be accessing the application offline (e.g. as a daemon)? Or because you wish to host your own username/password form? This is possible, but not recommended and I'd like to get a better sense of why before answering. :)

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I would like to invite some external users to the application and I don't want them to really know they have an account with my system. I don't want them to have to manage the username/passwords. It's a very small amount of people and I can deal with managing all that stuff myself, I just need to be able to log in for them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Resource Owner Credentials flow.  Assuming you're using [ADAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj573266.aspx), you can leverage [this sample app](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet) to retrieve a token.

Once you have the authentication result, you can use it to build an identity and pass that to the cookie authentication manager (assuming you're using the OWIN cookie authentication middleware).

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, result.UserInfo.GivenName));
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
 
var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```

Source: http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/

Comment: my application is not a web api, is there a way I can do a similar thing by signing them in and having it generate an auth cookie?

Comment: It doesn't need to be an API.  Look at the [client program](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet/blob/master/TodoListClient/Program.cs) - it takes a username/password and retrieves a token, which it then uses to call an API.

Comment: I understand that....but if I have a web application what does the token get me? The application is going to require a cookie to to be present or it will redirect to a login page. I need to be able to log someone in and then redirect them to my web app so they don't have to log in themselves.

Comment: Updated answer to show how to get the session cookie generated.